# Yii relation not working correctly (Yii 1.x)

Tags: database, yii, frameworks, relational-database

I have two models as follows:

```
MyuserClassroom - db table is called 'myuser_classrooms'
MyuserClassroomPivot - db table is called 'myuser_classrooms_pivot'
```

The structure is quite simple

```
myuser_classrooms(classroom_id, title, organisation_id, active)
myuser_classrooms_pivot(classroom_id, user_id)
```

Classroom ID in the pivot table is the foreign key (as is the user_id for the users table)

In the MyuserClassroom model I have the following relation

```
function relations() {
   return array(
      'classroomStudents' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'MyuserClassroomPivot', 'myuser_classrooms_pivot(classroom_id, user_id)')
   )
}
```

I simply want a collection of all of the rows in the pivot table by classroom_id but it doesn't work for me as I get an empty array.

Can anyone suggest what I am doing incorrectly?

This is an sql fiddle of the database
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37121f/1

// below is the query that Yii generates in the log of queries..

```
SELECT
`classroomStudents`.`classroom_id` AS `t1_c0`,
`classroomStudents`.`user_id` AS `t1_c1`
 FROM
`myuser_classrooms_pivot` `classroomStudents`
  INNER JOIN `myuser_classrooms_pivot` `classroomStudents_classroomStudents`   ON (
`classroomStudents_classroomStudents`.`classroom_id` = 4
)
 AND (
`classroomStudents`.`classroom_id` = `classroomStudents_classroomStudents`.`user_id` )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many-to-many relation between `User` and `MyuserClassroom` tables. But there is a has-many relation between `MyuserClassroom` and `MyuserClassroomPivot` tables.

So, if you want to grab rows from pivot table, write:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'pivots'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'MyuserClassroomPivot', 'classroom_id'),
    );
}
```

Note, in this case you should create `MyuserClassroomPivot` ActiveRecord Class for `myuser_classrooms_pivot` table.